# Reading the position of the comma using instr function in number with a lot of digits

Tags: excel, vba

When i use instr on numbers with a lot of digits, it shows first is 3 and second is 14 on the immediate window. Anybody knows how do you read it in this case?

```
Sub read()
    Dim sl As String
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim second As Integer

    sl = ".3, 4.858E-10, .100006103516"

    first = InStr(2, sl, ",", 1)
    second = InStr(first + 2, sl, ",", 1)
    Debug.Print (first)
    Debug.Print (second)
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what would be positions for second comma (,)?

Comment: @Harun24HR which second comma you referring to?

Comment: It is showing `3, 14` as output which is correct. So, what is wrong here?

Comment: so the value of first is 3 and the starting position of second is 5 hence Instr(5,sl, ",", 1) but the output says second is 14 so how do we read the digits or the number as a whole?

Comment: like why second is 14?

Comment: Start number is `5` but position is 14 from start. So do you want it read as `9` means `14-5=9`?

Comment: @Harun24HR like can you explain what 5 here refers to and what 14 here refers to?

Comment: It is the position from the left side of the string.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout yeah i understand that part. The thing im confused is normally in string, we count the alphabets so in the case of numbers, do we count the digits  to find the position of commas or something else?

Comment: No we do not count alphabets. We count "characters". Alphabets,Numbers,Spaces,Special Characters etcs...

Comment: @SiddharthRout if thats the case, for second, i try to count from starting position 5  which is respresented as "4" and when i finally found the position of the comma, i read 10 but the output says 14 which i am confused

Comment: `.3, 4.858E-10, .100006103516` Lets break it up...  `decimal` is at 1st postion. `3` is as 2nd, `first comma` is at 3rd. `Space` is at 4th, `4` is at 5th. `Decimal` is at 6th, `8` is at 7th, `5` is at 8th, `8` is at 9th, `E` is at 10th,, `-` is at 11th, `1` is at 12th, `0` is at 13th and the `Second comma` is at 14th position

Comment: @Siddharth Rout so   for second = InStr(5, sl, ",", 1), the 5 here does not mean count starting from the 5th position of the string from the left to the point where my comma is found?

Comment: `5` here means, start from the 5th position and give me the position of `,` in the **entire** string. If you want the postion of the `,` w.r.t to the 5th postion then you will have to substract `14 - 5` For example `InStr(5, sl, ",", 1) - 5`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout ah so it means regardless of the starting position, it will still count from the  very first left? But to find specific position, i have to make my own subtraction?

Comment: Yes. The benefit of specifying a `Start` like `5` is when you have multiple occurences of a string in a string and you want to work with a particular section of a string. For Example, extracting say name between two `#` in `This is a sample String which has a name # Cena # and the address is blah blah`

Comment: I recommend googling `VBA Instr` There are lot of exmaples in the web on `how` and `where` to use it .. with examples

Comment: @Siddharth Rout alright, thanks alot..

Comment: What Do you want to do with the positions? If you want to parse you string to numbers: have a look at the `Application.Split` function.